# Is it possible to make text float all the way round an image using CSS?

Tags: html, image, css, css-float

It's straightforward to have text flow around an image using `float: left` or `right`, but is it possible to have the text flow around an image placed in the center of the text? I guess what I really want would be a `float: center` or a `float: left 10%` - but of course that doesn't exist!

I have tried using display: inline-block but this doesn't seem to work (or I don't understand it) because the image is in effect treated like a character, and since the image height is much bigger than the line height, there is an unsightly gap in the text.

Here is some code to illustrate what I am trying to do. If you try it out you will see that the image is much bigger than the line height (which is how I want it).

```
    <p>Quisque laoreet sed erat at lobortis. Phasellus eu dolor id neque cursus egestas. Suspendisse potenti. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Vivamus sollicitudin consectetur nulla vitae ultrices? Pellentesque eget nisl et nunc faucibus maximus ac sit amet sapien. Etiam suscipit, eros vel porta consectetur, elit odio mattis lectus, vel fermentum urna eros eu nulla. Phasellus posuere, ipsum et efficitur aliquam, dolor erat posuere dui, et sollicitudin risus ante at augue. 
        <svg class="icon" style="align: center; float:none; display: inline-block;" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="70" height="70" >
            <path  d="M31.722 26.305h-9.23c-0.479 0-0.861-0.385-0.861-0.859 0-0.477 0.383-0.861 0.861-0.861h8.368v-8.371c0-0.474 0.385-0.859 0.861-0.859 0.472 0 0.859 0.385 0.859 0.859v9.232c0 0.474-0.387 0.859-0.859 0.859z"></path>
            <path  d="M23.351 32.317h23.408v-15.241h-14.683l-8.725 8.727v6.514zM47.618 34.040h-25.126c-0.479 0-0.861-0.387-0.861-0.861v-7.732c0-0.23 0.092-0.448 0.251-0.61l9.23-9.227c0.162-0.162 0.38-0.254 0.61-0.254h15.896c0.477 0 0.861 0.385 0.861 0.859v16.964c0 0.474-0.385 0.861-0.861 0.861z"></path>
            <path  d="M23.351 52.3h23.408v-6.784h-23.408v6.784zM47.618 54.020h-25.126c-0.479 0-0.861-0.385-0.861-0.861v-8.504c0-0.474 0.383-0.861 0.861-0.861h25.126c0.477 0 0.861 0.387 0.861 0.861v8.504c0 0.477-0.385 0.861-0.861 0.861z"></path>
            <path  d="M55.254 51.051h-5.385v-3.441h1.941v-12.488h-33.518v12.488h1.946v3.441h-5.387v-19.37h40.403v19.37z"></path>
            <path  d="M45.142 37.678c-1.12 0-2.023 0.908-2.023 2.026s0.904 2.026 2.023 2.026c1.12 0 2.026-0.908 2.026-2.026s-0.906-2.026-2.026-2.026z"></path>
            <path  d="M40.191 40.115h-10.577c-0.474 0-0.861-0.385-0.861-0.861 0-0.474 0.387-0.859 0.861-0.859h10.577c0.474 0 0.861 0.385 0.861 0.859 0 0.477-0.387 0.861-0.861 0.861z"></path>
        </svg>
        Etiam dignissim vehicula quam ut placerat. Maecenas commodo eros vel risus mattis fermentum. Duis sed sollicitudin nisi. Nam vulputate lectus eu pulvinar suscipit! Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Etiam sit amet nibh dictum, suscipit odio a, sagittis massa. Phasellus aliquam gravida orci quis sodales. Phasellus molestie blandit euismod. Phasellus orci justo, aliquet non maximus ac, accumsan vel arcu? Duis quam ligula; ultrices ac porta at, rhoncus bibendum nisl.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very vague but I hope this is what you meant.
If you must ... then crop and resize the image or simply use css to set the height of image and then put image in the middle of the text like an icone.

```
<p>
The value for signature is computed by clicking the symbol <img id="symbol" src="image.jpg"/> the same way as with the handover request to your action URI.
</p>

#symbol{
  height: 18px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

Comment: so you want to put the image in the middle of multiple lines?!?!?

Comment: Not Possible. it simply contradicts all css and html rules. you have to create few divs and style them accordingly to achieve this.